# How does ggplot in geom_line calculates interpolate its color?

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors

This question is an extension for answer/thought that I had in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50314457/r-inconsistent-p-value-in-running-spearman-correlation), were I first encountered this problem.

**My problem** is how `ggplot` interpolate the color between points, specifically under `geom_line` and the `color` aesthetics.

Example:

```
require(tidyverse)
#Example dataset
df <- data.frame(x = c(1:4), 
                 y = c(1, 3, 1, 3), 
                 color = c(10, 1, 10, 1))
#Graph
df %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x, y, color = color)) + 
  geom_line() +
  geom_point()
```

[image]

For example, in the graph above, the same "path" is one time (from point 1 to 2) "light blue" and another (from point 2 to 3) is "dark blue".
I am assuming that the idea is that the "path" between two points is colored by the last value. While generally is true or make sense, in some cases like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50314457/r-inconsistent-p-value-in-running-spearman-correlation) it might be incorrect and/or misleading.

**My questions**:

1. How does `ggplot` calculates the color of the path from one point to the next?
2. Do I have any way to control it?

Comment: Your other code throws errors. This seems to be a duplicate question.

Comment: fixing it :) I forgot to add the library.

Comment: Tricky question. The inner workings of ggplot2 are a mystery to a lot of people. It's possible to create a gradient in `geom_line` to better represent the acutal values, or transitions. Checkout this SO post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25906018/continuous-colour-of-geom-line-according-to-y-value This doesn't exactly answer your question but checkout the `ggplot_build` function that will generate an object with the values of all the different data points. You can see that the colour in geom_line has to alpha value.

Comment: Thank you! Maybe I could join both parts and interpolate a part under the ggplot_build or something like that.  
It is not a perfect answer but definitely deserve an up-vote. You should write it as an answer :)